# Primeng2 Angular2 table wordwrap fails

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

Primeng2 wordwrap on columns fails to work.

Am trying to break columns with long sentences to new lones but this fails

```
          <p-dataTable [value]="tcentercomment"
                   [responsive]="true" #dt2
                    resizableColumns="true" columnResizeMode="expand"  >

            <p-column field="item_id" [styleClass]="break-column" header="Item" [sortable]="true" [filter]="false"></p-column>
            <p-column field="message" [styleClass]="break-column" header="Comment passed" [sortable]="true" [filter]="false"></p-column>

        </p-dataTable>
```

In my css

```
.break-column, .ui-cell-data{
    word-wrap: break-word;        
    width: 100%;
}
```

But with long columns the data doesnt break to a new line.

Comment: I tested it in a plunker and it works: https://plnkr.co/edit/0GGNyikQj8tTcaCycyPK?p=preview

Comment: Try this `<p-dataTable tableStyleClass="break-column"` also in style.css have a class `.break-column {
    word-wrap: break-word;        
    width: 100%;
}` . Here instead of applying class on individual column, we are applying it on whole table.